# Prove that $x^n$ is o(n!)

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Prove that for $ x \in \mathbb{R}$ $x^n$ is o(n!) 
I know that here we can use the definition of $e^{x}$ ,
But I would like to prove it with the limit definition, 
So $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ would ratio test completely suffice here? Or are there other methods?

Comment: Is $n$ the variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any integer $k >2|x|$. Note that $n! >(k)(k)... (k)=k^{n-k}$ if $n >k$. Hence $|\frac {x^{n}} {n!}|<k^{k} (\frac   1 2 )^{n} \to 0$

Comment: Thank you so much,  very elegant solution